# Circuit or device for avoiding electrical overload

Tags: power, power-electronics, mains

Is there any device that can limit current to 2 appliances connected in parallel on the same outlet?

Let's say both devices A and B can draw upto 10 amps but can work under reduced current as well (say 5A each).

So I want something to be installed in the outlet (rated for say 15-16A) that will limit the current to 10 amps so that the circuit breaker doesn't trip.

Comment: What are these devices? And under what conditions do they consume 5A rather than 10A?

Comment: Hey Steve! They are battery chargers. But the control circuit has to installed on the outlet side. I can't touch the load.

Comment: How do they know when to reduce current?

Comment: During start of charging, it detects variations in line voltage and drops current. Its also user configurable but I want a solution that doesn't require me to manually adjust each charger's current in case I am connecting both in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

"Is there a device?" There is probably nothing that you can buy that will do that. You can prevent the breaker from tripping by installing a fast-acting breaker with a lower current, but that just shuts the loads off nearby rather than elsewhere.

Could you design something?" If the loads act like resistors, a device that reduces the voltage would reduce the current, but it is not very likely that the loads act like resistors.

You could design chargers that do what you want, but they would probably need to be interconnected so that all of the chargers can set their charging current according to the number of connected chargers.

Comment: Hey Charles!Thanks for helping out. I cannot modify the load circuitry. Said that, I was thinking of maybe current limiting resistor in series before the load? Is that doable? Ofcourse given I get the resistor in the required wattage.